# ZXing.Net.Mobile in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, qr-code, zxing

I am using `ZXing.Net.Mobile` in my windows phone 8.1 app. It is using below reference:

- ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core
- zxing.portable
- ZXingNetMobile

**My Code :**

```
var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();

MobileBarcodeScanningOptions options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
options.TryHarder = true;
options.PossibleFormats.Add(ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128);
options.PossibleFormats.Add(ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_39);

var result = await scanner.Scan(options);

if (result != null)
{
    MessageDialog a = new MessageDialog(result.Text);
    a.Content = result.Text;
    a.ShowAsync();
}
```

**Issue:**
Am getting below issue whenever scan method executes.
Use the platform specific implementations instead at `ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner.Scan(`....

Is there any real time QR code scanner available for windows phone 8.1 ?